# How to configure auto scale for apps having batch jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-configuration, azure-autoscaling-block

**Problem:**
We have App Service Plan (P1v3:1) which has 6 java apps , out of which 2 apps have batch jobs (Spring @Scheduled) scheduled to run every 1 hour. We have 1 app , which renders data to UI and handles most of the traffic. We found the issue org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 503 Instance is overloaded for that app service alone.

**What is tried?**
We have set scale in and scale out conditions for memory > 70 % to scale up and to scale down if <70%.We noticed that it is being applied to all the app services running in the app service plan, though other app services are not hitting 70% memory or less used.

**Question:**
Now , if the **instance count is more than one for the services running batch** , **will the job run twice?**(because they are 2 independent java apps)

**Update** : They are running twice , is it possible to set autoscale to only 1 app service ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure supports per site scaling. We can explicitly set how many instances can a app service scale , irrespective of app-service-plan auto scale.
For example, Auto Scale condition is 5 instances, you can restrict specific app service to 1 instance only.

More here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-per-app